# Where does the rest of msg.value go?

Tags: solidity

If not all of the `msg.value` is used, does it get returned to `msg.sender` or do I need to write a function that returns unused `msg.value` back to `msg.sender`?

I want to allow users to buy a token for x value and I'm wondering if the value passed in is more than the price, what should I do with the remaining `msg.value`?

```
function buyToken() payable returns (bool) {
    require(tokens[owner] >= 1 && msg.value >= price);

    // transfer the price of token to the owner, to be withdrawn later
    owner.transfer(msg.value.sub(price));

    tokens[owner] = tokens[owner].sub(1);
    tokens[msg.sender] = tokens[msg.sender].add(1);

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When a `payable` function is called the value paid is automatically transferred to the balance of the contract. If you had a payable function that didn't do anything, all the value would still stay in the contract.

So if you want to return funds to the sender, you will need to explicitly `transfer` the change back to them. However, unless the price is changing in real time, it may be preferable to require the sender to send the right amount, and simply `revert` the transaction if they don't.

Comment: Also for some reason when my require(msg.value >= price) doesn't trigger in Remix when I test it. In fact I created a separate function that only returns msg.value and it doesn't return anything.

Comment: If you're OK aborting if the price is wrong then you can just change the first line to `require(msg.value == price);`. A failed `require` causes a `revert`, leaves the user with the money they started with, minus gas costs.